# Has anyone here tried using ZWAMP as a dedicated SQL instance for long-term data collection?

Tags: mysql, sql

By "ZWAMP", I mean [this product](http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/), especially its MySQL implementation.

What I'm really aiming to learn here are the inherent, hardware independent, data storage size, complexity, and duration limitations associated with that software, if any; and whether it would be a very bad idea for me to put a ZWAMP instance onto a dedicated server (I'm running Windows Server 2012, but any server will do, I suppose) with plenty of storage space, and dump large (several tb) quantities of complex relational/historical data into it, with maybe up to a hundred simultaneous clients pulling and writing.

Suggestions for, or comparisons to, alternative free or equivalent WAMPs or SQL implementations are fine, but also please answer the questions as they pertain to ZWAMP in particular.

Comment: It's not been [active for 8+ years](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zwamp/files/). It would be a ***very*** bad idea to put 8 year old server software into production.

Comment: @vidarlo The sourceforge front page is a bit misleading -- the original designer, Bosca, hasn't updated it in 8 years, but it's GPL open source, and the project has been taken up by Cheejyg with updates as recent as 2021/06/11 (see here: https://sourceforge.net/p/zwamp/discussion/1093015/thread/5111873609/ )

Comment: But I suppose that won't change your advice lol. It doesn't seem to have been designed with commercial use in mind; I'm just curious if it *can* be used that way.

Comment: yes, it can. It's just a distribution of various components. For a production environment it's probably better to go to upstream, or a reputable vendor such as Debian or Redhat for bundles...

Comment: Running large queries against TBs of data is likely to cause a meltdown.  You need either smart software designed for TBs (there doesn't seem to be such), or you need a smart SQL programmer.